# How to query on multiple databases with different users in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query to update some data on database A from database B. Normally in this case I just give permission to a user to have access to both databases, but in this case databases are both on different hostings, so I cannot add a user to both databases.

In SSMS when I want to write the query (based on the connection) I only have access to one of the databases.

I don't have the privilege to add a linked server either.

How can I query on both databases?

Comment: Sounds to me like you just cannot write queries that access both databases. So, write a program in whatever programming langauge, connect to both databases, query data from the databases, and use your programming langauge to loop throgh the data and do whatever you want.

Comment: I agree, I wanted to go with an easy option as this will be done only once. but as you mentioned I think that is the way I need to go.

Comment: Do you have permissions to run SQLCMD?

Comment: you can use openrowset and connect to both places

Comment: @siggemannen openrowset doesn't work either no privilege to run `EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1`

Comment: OK, can you ask some admin to create some linked servers then?